# Как правильно составить регулярку?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть html документ, там есть выражение вида:

```
html5player.setVideoUrlHigh('https://vid-egc.lfiles-cdn.com/videos/mp4/1/9/7/198cb6a5b437e481554da8b2755023c9.mp4?D2OIFKqeESql03biPXww_djuYRPnEa1djBZKVuAoCLxxdq6iYmhpaufW1U-EZaS7JK7Pg2ftsLx5171nhCl5pzYKA23-arLSbSTBQ5-2BLIabJD278ua0PkNoAzOuitU1ihhsTZ-uZM8vsw5moiPbDtuz-ThOBadzOPFwjaPrJnhjjsY_0lMkf0wsHqZ9zrKeRzTv1kA0QA');
```

Как правильно составить регулярку, чтобы вытянуть то что находится между (' ')?
Пробовал так:

```
/^html5player.setVideoUrlHigh('\s(.*)\z');/Uis
```

Но почему-то не работает(мб потому что я криворукий xD).Может кто помочь с составлением?Был был весьма благодарен)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте такой шаблон:

```
$str = "html5player.setVideoUrlHigh('https://vid-egc.lfiles-cdn.com/videos/mp4/1/9/7/198cb6a5b437e481554da8b2755023c9.mp4?D2OIFKqeESql03biPXww_djuYRPnEa1djBZKVuAoCLxxdq6iYmhpaufW1U-EZaS7JK7Pg2ftsLx5171nhCl5pzYKA23-arLSbSTBQ5-2BLIabJD278ua0PkNoAzOuitU1ihhsTZ-uZM8vsw5moiPbDtuz-ThOBadzOPFwjaPrJnhjjsY_0lMkf0wsHqZ9zrKeRzTv1kA0QA');";

$patt = "~html5player\.setVideoUrlHigh\('([^\']+)'\)~";
preg_match_all($patt, $str, $a);

var_dump($a[1]);
```

Comment: При попытке закрыть в ковычки '' внутри preg_match php ругается, и ничего не находит.Саму ссылку пытаюсь вытянуть из спаршенного js скрипта, но сомневаюсь что в этом может быть проблема, т.к. регулярка обрабатывает переменную же как обычную строку.

Comment: @Mastas я с телефона писал и не учёл скобки -- обновил свой ответ.